# Incorrect password in Kali Linux

Tags: kali-linux, grub2, dual-boot, grub, password

I have my Kali Linux and Windows dual booted. It had been a few days since I logged in to my Kali Linux but when I tried to login today, it says my password is incorrect. It was working fine before. I am 100% sure that I am entering the correct password. The problem is I have disabled the advanced options in grub. I am not being able to do anything to login to kali. What can I do?

Comment: do you have a way to see what you type? Maybe you are typing the right keys but your keyboard layout has changed for some reason.

Comment: The usual thing in this situation is to boot a rescue environment and reset the password that way. My favourite is [SysrescueCD](https://www.system-rescue.org/) but there will be others

Comment: @ewen-goisot I tried that, but Kali has no option show the typed password. I checked for the keyboard layout in options, and it is US English.

Comment: @roaima I will try this